# Create ID column from row in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyverse, purrr

I am having below data frame:

Input:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c('id','a','b','c','d','id','a','b','c','d','id','a','b','c','d','id','a','b','c','d','id','a','b','c','d'),
          value=c(1,'a1','b1','c1','d1',2,'a2','b2','c2','d2',3,'a3','b3','c3','d3',4,'a4','b4','c4','d4',5,'a5','b5','c5','d5'),
          )
```

I want to create new column `id` and rows below first `id` should be assigned under that `id`.

Desired Output:

```
output <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5),
                     var=c('a','b','c','d','a','b','c','d','a','b','c','d','a','b','c','d','a','b','c','d'),
                     value=c('a1','b1','c1','d1','a2','b2','c2','d2','a3','b3','c3','d3','a4','b4','c4','d4','a5','b5','c5','d5'))
```

**NOTE:** The solution should also work for cases like this:

```
df <- data.frame(a=c('id','a','b','c','d','id','a','b','c','d','id','a','b','c','d','id','a','b','c','d','id','a','b','c','d'),
          value=c('id1','a1','b1','c1','d1','id12','a2','b2','c2','d2','idd3','a3','b3','c3','d3','i44','a4','b4','c4','d4','i15','a5','b5','c5','d5')
          )

expected_output <- data.frame(id=c('id1','id1','id1','id1','id12','id12','id12','id12','idd3','idd3','idd3','idd3','i44','i44','i44','i44','i15','i15','i15','i15'),
                     var=c('a','b','c','d','a','b','c','d','a','b','c','d','a','b','c','d','a','b','c','d'),
                     value=c('a1','b1','c1','d1','a2','b2','c2','d2','a3','b3','c3','d3','a4','b4','c4','d4','a5','b5','c5','d5'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your edits, I think this works:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  mutate(id = ifelse(a == "id", as.character(value), NA)) %>%
  fill(id) %>%
  filter(a != "id")
#    a value   id
# 1  a    a1  id1
# 2  b    b1  id1
# 3  c    c1  id1
# 4  d    d1  id1
# 5  a    a2 id12
# 6  b    b2 id12
# 7  c    c2 id12
# 8  d    d2 id12
# 9  a    a3 idd3
# 10 b    b3 idd3
# 11 c    c3 idd3
# 12 d    d3 idd3
# 13 a    a4  i44
# 14 b    b4  i44
# 15 c    c4  i44
# 16 d    d4  i44
# 17 a    a5  i15
# 18 b    b5  i15
# 19 c    c5  i15
# 20 d    d5  i15
```

The rule for making it generic is not super clear. In the first case, the `value` corresponding to `a == "id"` does not start with the letter "id", and you want to add it on.

The second case is more confusing, some values start with "id", others just with "i", and nothing is added on. I don't understand why "i44" is a good id as is "idd3", but not "1". My best guess is that anything starting with an "i" is okay, but otherwise we will paste on "id". 
We can do this in a simple post-processing step. I use "starts with `'i'`" as the criteria, and I'll leave it to you adjust to whatever the real criteria are.

```
df %>%
  mutate(id = ifelse(a == "id", as.character(value), NA_character_)) %>%
  fill(id) %>%
  filter(a != "id") %>%
  mutate(id = ifelse(grepl("^i", id), id, paste0("id", id)))
```

The above matches your expected output for both inputs.

Answer (score 2):

Among other options:

```
library(stringr)
df %>%
  filter(a != "id") %>%
  mutate(id = str_extract(value, "\\d+$"))
```

Or:

```
df %>%
  mutate(id = if_else(a == "id", value, factor(NA))) %>%
  fill(id) %>%
  filter(a != "id")
```

Comment: Even this will fail, if id is not a part of value.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R solution.

```
df$id <- cumsum(df$a == 'id')
df <- df[df$a != 'id', ]
names(df)[1] <- 'var'
df <- df[c(3, 1, 2)]
```

Here is a `dplyr` solution.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(id = cumsum(a == 'id')) %>%
  filter(a != 'id') %>%
  rename(var = a) %>%
  select(id, var, value)
```

Comment: this will fail, if id is not numeric.

Comment: @RushabhPatel No, it does not fail if `id` is numeric. It only depends on the value of the "break" values, when `a == 'id'`.